# how to set enable a button on previous activity

Tags: android

I have an activities A>B. in activity A there's a 2 buttons. button1 is in enabled state and button2 is in disabled state. when you click button1 you will go to activity B. in activity B there is a button that when you click, you will go back to activity A and then the button2 should be set to enabled. the problem is after it has been set to enabled state, it will turn back to disabled. can you guys give me a better way to set the button enabled?

here is my activity A

```
public class Enable extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enable);


    Button page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), p2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        }
    });

    Button page2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    page2.setEnabled(false);
    page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), p2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

        }
    });
}
```

here is my Activity B

```
public class p2 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.p2);

    Button page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Enable.class);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_enable);
            Button a = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            a.setEnabled(true);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);


        }
    });

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't your try something like this:-

Send whether you want to **enable or disable** the button, as `boolean` from `Activity`B as part of `Intent`

```
myIntent.putExtra("isEnabled", "enabled");
```

In your `Activity`A, check for the `boolean`, sent from activity B. If its true, then **enable** the button in your `onCreate()`, and if, its `null` or `false`, **disable** it.

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
String isEnabled = intent.getStringExtra("isEnabled");
if(isEnabled==null||isEnabled.equals("disabled")){
        page2.setEnabled(false);
}
else{
        page2.setEnabled(true);
}
```

This will solve your problem, for any case. That way, you can enable/disable that button, no matter, from which `Activity` you come.

Comment: do you know how to set the button permanently enabled? so that after it is setEnabled it should be enabled even if the user exits the application using onbackpress

Comment: Once, the user enables it, you can write it to a file and persist it. And then, everytime your app starts, you can read that file, check what the data in that, and accordingly, enable/disable the button.

Comment: I used the code you post above. How can I write it on a file?

Answer (score 0):

You need not make a call to Enable from class p2. You would just have to call finish(). This would return to the calling Activity which in this case is Enable.
An alternate way to do it would be to set an extra when you call Enable from p2. So it would be like :

```
myIntent.putExtra("isEnabled", "enabled");
```

and in the getIntent() of the Enabled activity you would do something like :

```
getIntent();
String isEnabled = intent.getStringExtra("isEnabled");
page2.setEnabled(isEnabled.equals("enabled") ? true : false) ;
```

Comment: but now my problem is how can I set it permanently enabled? so that even when the user exits the application it would still be in enabled state? my goal is to create a game with certain levels. and I want to do is when the user finish a certain level the next level button will enabled(in which I already done) and set it permanently enabled.

Comment: You could set this : android:alwaysRetainTaskState="True" on the manifest file

Comment: I already tried it but when I exit the app using onbackpress and reopen it again, it still remained disabled.

Answer (score 0):

In B Activity

```
Button page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("Button", "enabled"); 
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

}

In A Activity

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
String enable = intent.getStringExtra("Button");
if(enable.equals("enabled")){
page2.setEnabled(true);
}
else{
page2.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this on my Enabled activity

`Button page2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
  
  Intent intent=getIntent();
  String enable = intent.getStringExtra("Button");
  if(enable.equals("enabled")){
  page2.setEnabled(true);
  }
  else{
  page2.setEnabled(false);
  }
  
  page2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View view) {
    
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), p2.class);
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
    
   }
  });` but im having a null pointer error on logcat on the line `if(enable.equals("enabled")){`

Comment: fine dude happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

  public final static int SHOW_ACTIVITY_B = 10;
  public final static String RESULT_ENABLE_BTN2 = "enable_btn2";

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enable);


    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(View view) {
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ActivityB.class);
         startActivityForResult(myIntent, SHOW_ACTIVITY_B);
       }
    });

    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btn2.setEnabled(false);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {
         // Do whatever you need with button #2
         // ...
      }
    });

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      if( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED ) {
        // in this case ActivityB returned this code explicitly,
        // or any result at all, or even crashed
      }
      else if( requestCode == SHOW_ACTIVITY_B ) {
        btn2.setEnabled( data.getBooleanExtra( RESULT_ENABLE_BTN2, false ) );
      }
    }
}
```

while `ActivityB` should look like this:

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.p2);


    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent output = getIntent();
        output.putExtra( ActivityA.RESULT_ENABLE_BTN2, true );
        setResult(RESULT_OK, output);
        finish();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Note that a call to `startActivityForResult(...)` should be used in conjuction with `setResult(...)` + `finish()` on the called activity, in order to use this feature properly. Your previous code you does not use it at all, because the second activity launches a new instance of the first activity instead. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Jerome you're welcome. If it has been useful please consider to mark my answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

you should use `onActivityResult()`. i see that u start activity b like

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), p2.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
```

try:

in your `B Activity` when page1 button clicked , just write these code(just these):

```
setResult(0,null);
finish();
```

then in your `A Activity` use these code, first make your `Button page2` `Button page1` global. then

```
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == 0)
           page2.setEnabled(true);

    }
```